# Jade template with variables (nodejs server side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

So i want to show a contacts list and for that I have transformed each contact div into jade code, but I still have to populate the relevant fields. Can I do that on the server side? I'm using nodejs for server code. The jade template of a contact is:

```
//  
    img-cont
    .img-cont
      //
        img-cont
      .left-img
        //
          left-img
        .img-box
          img(src='assets/img/img.jpg', alt='')
        .name
          h6
            span John Doe
            img(src='assets/img/star-b.png', alt='')
          p
            strong Phone number:
            | +1 234 567890
          p
            strong Email address:
            a(href='mailto:mail@company.com') mail@company.com
      //
        left-img
      ul.share-ul
        li
              a.edit(href='#') Edit
        li
          a.share(href='#') Share
        li
          a.delete(href='#') Delete
    //
      img-cont
```

So instead of having John Doe and the random phone number if there was a way to signify that i'd like variables over there, and then the nodeJS code would stick in the right values in there and add the contact jade to the main jade page, and then go to the next contact and so on. So something similar to this: http://embeddedjs.com/

I'm using express as a framework for Nodejs.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes you can do that when you call render pass the object with data

```
res.render('your page', {pageData: {name : ['name 1', 'name 2']}});
```

Then inside jade you can do

```
span #{pageData.name[0]}
```

or if you want a loop

```
each item in pageData.name
  span #{item}
```

You can find more on the github page https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

Comment: Or jade-lang.com but the examples in the Git tree are probably the best documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to access the name of the page from inside a template? E.g. pageTitle= #{'your page'}

Comment: Thanks. The most important example and you cannot see it in the main Jade page...

Comment: Very nic answer :)