# Pass vars with Nodejs from controller to view not working

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm not able to pass a var from a controller to a view with Nodejs.

Currently, I'm using express, and this is my route definition

```
app.get('/search/:id', function(req,res){
    searchController.findByName(req, res);
    // console.log(res);                        //--->Check res is right
    res.render('search', { test: 'test' });
});
```

searchController has this code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var search = mongoose.model('products');

exports.findByName=function(req, res){
    var regex = new RegExp("^"+req.params.id, 'i');
    search.find(
        {'name': regex}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
        res.status(200).json(result);
    });
};
```

Connection to mongoDB is right using mongoose. If I console.log(res) in my controller, I obtain a quite hudge JSON file (more than 500 lines!), but I can't find the results of the query to the database.

I take an empty array from the database, I've checked with Postman. This means, problem is not in the database:

[image]

Is it normal to have this so long JSON file? I know I can send data to the view with the second argument  How could I pass the query from the controler to the view with `res.render('search', { test: 'test' });`, but test is also unknown in the view, no matter if I also write `res.render('search', { 'test': 'test' });`

Thanks!

### ** UPDATE **

Thanks to Mike's answer I've refactored my code to the following:

#### ** Route **

```
app.get('/search/:id', function(req,res){
    searchController.findByName(req, res);
});
```

#### ** Controller **

```
exports.findByName=function(req, res){
    var regex = new RegExp("^"+req.params.id, 'i');
    search.find(
        {'name': regex}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);
        console.log(result);  //--> NEW console.log inside controller, works
        res.render('search', {'result': result});
    });
};
```

Now result is an empty array (which is the right value from the database) but still is not rendering this var in the view.

#### ** VIEW FILES **

**`search.jade`**

```
include search.php
```

**`search.php`**

```
<script>
     var productsJSON = result;
</script>
```

### ** SECOND UPDATE **

Thanks to Mike's answer (again), I'm doing some progress. Now my contoller is:

```
exports.findByName=function(req, res){
    var regex = new RegExp("^"+req.params.id, 'i');
    search.find(
        {'name': regex}, function(err, result) {
        if(err) return res.send(500, err.message);  
        res.render('search', {'pageData': {'result' : result}});
    });
};
```

I've added **''** to pageData because I think must be there.

Now my views are:

**search.jade**

```
include header.php

script.
  var productsJSON = #{pageData.result}
```

But is not working, I've the following error:

[image]

I've tried to follow some of the tricks shown [in this page](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-make-a-variable-passed-to-a-jade-template-by-an-express-route-accessible-for-use-in-js-on-the-rendered-page) but is not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are responding twice when this endpoint is hit.  You are sending a response with `res.render('search', { test: 'test' });` and also with `res.status(200).json(result);`.

Try moving `res.render('search', { test: 'test' });` in place of `res.status(200).json(result);`.  You will then only have one chance of responding from this endpoint.

The large JSON response object is correct.  That is what the response object looks like.  It should include a bunch of stuff like it does in your example above.

To display your data in the Jade template you will need to use the following syntax as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931531/jade-template-with-variables-nodejs-server-side).

Respond like this:
`res.render('search', {pageData: {'result' : result}});`

Then in your template render the value like this:
`#{pageData.result}`

You need to wrap any variables passed from the server side in `#{}` if you want them to display in the template.

Comment: What value are you getting for 'test' in your view?  Can you post your view code as well?

Comment: Thanks Mike! We're closed, but still jade is not rendering the object on the correct way

Comment: Try wrapping your object in `JSON.stringify`. Example: `JSON.stringify(#{pageData.result})`